Multiple Adsterra Banner Ads in Next.js
If anyone is still strugling with add multiple Adsterra Banner Ads in Next.js, Here is the solution
export default function Banner_300x250() {

  return (
    <div
      className="flex items-center justify-center"
    >
      <iframe
        src={`//example.com/watchnew?key=your_unique_key_here`}
        width="320px"
        height="250px"
        scrolling="no"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

NOTE: Replace your_unique_key_here and example.com from your script (provided by Adsterra)

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78889562/11991177
I can't upvote or comment because i am a new user. That's why i am posting a question instead to help others. I have been personally strugling with this issue for a long time.
